# Using netcat to scan hosts and ports

Tags: networking, bash, scripts

I have to use netcat to scan hosts and ports. The hosts are in the hostfile and the ports in the portfile. I have to read line by line of each file and use netcat to see if the ports are enabled, disabled or invalid and, finally, send this information into a file called scan_report.txt

```
netcatfunction()
{

local portfile=$2
local hostfile=$4

paste $2 $4 | while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read -r f1 f2
do
        result1=$( nc -zvw1 $f2 $f1 | grep succeeded )
        $( $result1 > scan_report.txt)

done
}

netcatfunction $2 $4
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @user68186 ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What is your question, exactly? I guess you are not getting the result you expect (remember that inside a function, `$2` and `$4` refer to the positional parameters *passed to the function* - of which you only have 2)

Comment: @steeldriver I have a hostfile and a portfile like this:
Portfile
80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

testNet(){
        nc -zw 1 $1 $2
        if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
                echo "$1 was listening on $2"
                echo "$2 was open on $1" >> scan_report.txt
        else
                echo "$1 was not listening on $2"
        fi

}


for host in $(cat hostfile); do
        for port in $(cat portfile); do
                testNet $host $port &
        done
done
sleep 2
cp scan_report.txt sorter
cat sorter | sort > scan_report.txt
rm sorter
```

Explanation:

The bulk of the "lifting" is inside of a function so that it can but run in parallel with `&`. This will spawn a subprocess for each host and port in your test, and not make you wait the sum of every one second timeout from the `nc` command. While the `nc` command is happening, the primary script will continue. This shouldn't pose a problem in terms of resources, because each process is going to last a maximum of one second due to the timeout.

As for what's going on, first it's reading one host from the hostfile, then it's reading each port from the portfile. It combines each host with each port and passes it to the testNet function, which executes the `nc` command and determines whether the connection was successful by checking the status output variable `$?`, which returns "0" for success. Anything else is interpreted as a failure.
the >> redirector ensures that each result is appended to the file, and doesn't completely overwrite it.

Finally, at the end of the script, the result is sorted alphabetically and sent back to the file.

This assumes that hosts are either raw IP addresses or FQDN's, and that ports are just numbers like "22". if you wanted to test every port over a range and not have to list them out line by line, you could replace `for port in $(cat portsfile); do` with `for((i=1;i!=20;i++)); do` which would test every port from 1 to 19 (replace 20 with the desired max and 1 with the desired minimum).